# Razorpay cordova plugin not working for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, razorpay

I'm trying to implement razorpay checkout in my ionic application using [Razorpay-cordova](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova). After installing this plugin, ios application gets stuck on its splash screen and then gets close. **Although this plugin works perfectly on Android and browser platforms**.

I have done following basic steps:

Started a blank app - `ionic start myApp sidemenu`

Added an ios platform - `ionic cordova platform add ios`

Than added razorpay plugin - `cordova plugin add com.razorpay.cordova --save`

After this I emulate this basic app just in ios simulator - `ionic cordova emulate ios`

**Result:** The app gets stuck on the splash screen for few secs and then gets close. (Only on IOS. Also tested on IOS device, results in same!).

I don't know what I'm missing here?

Comment: do you have any crash log?

Comment: No. nothing is shown in console log. Thats the major problem.

Comment: In mentioned plugin readme file, there are some notes related to xcode version, have you gone through it?

Comment: I dint embedded swift libraries in Xcode. That was the issue! 
Thank you for the response

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed swift libraries in Xcode(Which I forgot). Will work!

[image: Xcode screen shot]

Comment: how did you embed swift libraries, can you please help?

Comment: check out the answer again @KevinRED